# Basis of row space and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

If given some vectors, and asked to find a basis for the subspace of R(n),
will the basis for the *subspace* be the same as the basis for the *row* space?

example:

given the following vectors:
(1,1,4,-3),(2,0,2,-2),(2,-1,3,2)

we can construct the matrix

```
| 1 1 4 -3 |
| 2 0 2 -2 |
| 2 -1 3 2 |
```

and by reducing it to *row echelon form* we get

```
| 1 1 4 -3  |
| 0 1 -5 -2 |
| 0 0 1 -0.5|
```

therefore:

```
row(A) = { (1,1,-4,-3) , (0,1,-5,-2) , (0,0,1,-0,5) }
```

Will the basis for the *subspace* be the exact same thing?

Comment: Careful: $row(A) = span\{R_1, R_2,R_2\}$. The way you have it now makes it seem like there are only three vectors in the row space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:  The answer to your question is yes.

The row space of a matrix is the subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ spanned by its row vectors.  Therefore, the basis for your row space of this matrix will provide a basis for the subspace spanned by your original vectors.

Comment: Would the column space also be part of the subspace? Because when we use row operations it messes up the columns right?

Comment: Assuming your matrix A has m rows and n columns. The row space is a subspace of $R^n$ and the column space is a subspace of $R^m$.